# How to make a separate withdrawal of the rating sum from the button in js?

Tags: javascript, django

due to not knowing js, I cannot make it work and update when the button is clicked (one of the reactions)
just one counter, not built into the button. As I understand it, the fault is $ (this) in the function. But what way is there writing to change the counter of the amount of rating between the buttons? This code is added to 9 more posts in addition to this.

```
         <button class="btn-like-up" data-id="{{ post.id }}" type="button" data-type="file" data-action="rate_up">
             <i class="bi bi-chevron-up"></i>
         </button>
            <!-- COUNTER --> 
         <span data-count="total_rating">{{ post.total_rating }}</span>
          <!-- / COUNTER --> 
          <button class="btn-like-down" data-id="{{ post.id }}" type="button" data-type="file" data-action="rate_down">
             <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i>
              <span data-count="total_rating">{{ post.total_rating }}</span>
         </button>
```

When it is alone, it does not update the rating digit when clicked.

```
    $('.btn-like.up').submit('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let ratingBox = $(this).data('id')
    let postType = ratingBox.data('type')
    let postId = ratingBox.data('id')
    let postAction = ratingBox.data('action')
    let totalRating = ratingBox.find('[data-count="total_rating"]')

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/system/' + postType + '/' + postId + '/' + postAction + '/',
        data: {
            'post_id': postId,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
        },
        success: function(response) {
            totalRating.text(response.total_rating);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
    })
})

$('.btn-like.down').submit('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    let ratingBox = $(this).data('id')
    let postType = ratingBox.data('type')
    let postId = ratingBox.data('id')
    let postAction = ratingBox.data('action')
    let totalRating = ratingBox.find('[data-count="total_rating"]')

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/system/' + postType + '/' + postId + '/' + postAction + '/',
        data: {
            'post_id': postId,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
            totalRating.text(response.total_rating);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
    })
})
```

Comment: FYI: It's not valid HML to have a div inside a button tag.

Comment: This is a test. It doesn't matter at all. The important thing is that the span works inside, and I need it to work outside.
rate up / count / rate down

Comment: Hi, please can you elaborate more on your problem? Also , there are mutliple such buttons ?If yes can you show proper html ?

Comment: updated code and view in ntml

Comment: Oh guys, I did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `data-span="{{ post.id }}"` to your `totalRating` span .Then , whenever user click on any button you can get `data-id` and use that to refer span tag i.e : `$("span[data-span=" + postId + "]")` . Also , you can combine both button events as one because i don't see any difference between them .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//use only one ..event handler ..
$('.btn-like-up ,.btn-like-down').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let ratingBox = $(this) //refer to your button
  let postType = ratingBox.data('type')
  let postId = ratingBox.data('id')
  let postAction = ratingBox.data('action')
  let totalRating = $("span[data-span=" + postId + "]") //refer to span..tag between button
  console.log(postId, postAction)
  /*$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    //other codes
    success: function(response) {*/
  //just for demo..
  var response = {
    "total_rating": 90
  }
  totalRating.text(response.total_rating);
  /* },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
  })*/
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-like-up" data-id="1" type="button" data-type="file" data-action="rate_up">
             <i class="bi bi-chevron-up">Up</i>
         </button>
<!--added data-span="{{ post.id }}"-->
<span data-span="1" data-count="total_rating">12</span>
<button class="btn-like-down" data-id="1" type="button" data-type="file" data-action="rate_down"><i class="bi bi-chevron-down">Down</i>
 </button>
<br/>
<button class="btn-like-up" data-id="2" type="button" data-type="file" data-action="rate_up">
             <i class="bi bi-chevron-up">Up</i>
         </button>
<span data-span="2" data-count="total_rating">12</span>
<button class="btn-like-down" data-id="2" type="button" data-type="file" data-action="rate_down"><i class="bi bi-chevron-down">Down</i>
 </button>
```

Comment: It's a beatiful! Thanks!